# Closed form solution to $\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{e^{ic\sqrt{1+ br^2(\theta)}}}{\sqrt{1+ br^2(\theta)}}\,d\theta$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, line-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Is there closed form solution to this integral
 $$\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{e^{ic\sqrt{1+ br^2(\theta)}}}{\sqrt{1+ br^2(\theta)}}\,d\theta$$

$r(\theta)=\frac{a}{\cos(\theta)}$ is radius vector from the origin tracing square with side 2a (0,45 deg).

$c=$ constant, $b=$ constant.
[image]

Comment: Interesting question. What have you attempted so far? Also, what are $b$ and $c$?

Comment: Hint: What does differentiating the integral with respect to $c$ give you?

Comment: Thanks. What substitution would solve the integral after differentiating.